# Extracting text from leaf nodes using DomDocument in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument, dom-traversal

I am  retrieving different webpages using PHP, and then loading them to a DomDocument, however I am having a problem extracting the text only from leaf nodes.

For example, suppose I have the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="this_is_our_div_of_interest">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                    <div>Some <a href='#'>more</a> text</div>
                    <p>And <span><strong>another</strong></span> paragraph</p>
                </div>
                <p>Yay<p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>abcd</ph4>
                xyz
            <div>
        </div>
        <div class="we_do_not_want_those_divs">
            <p>This text is not important to us</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this is a messy input, however the expected "echo'ed" output is:

```
Some text
Some more text
And another paragraph
Yay
abcd
xyz
```

Note the following in the output

1. I only retrieve output from a specific tag (in our exmaple, `this_is_our_div_of_interest`)
2. The isn't a specific format for the tree supplied above bevcause it comes from a webpage tjat I cannot control its content, however, I only like to bring content of tags such as **div** and **p** that appear to be leaf nodes
3. There are some tags that need to be ommited, such as **a**, **span**, and **strong** (others maybe added to the list)

**UPDATE**
I am using xpath to get to the class, for example, the following line of code will bring all decendents as separete nodes:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='this_is_our_div_of_interest']/descendant::*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html');
$id = $dom->getElementById('youNeedAnIdForThis');
```

Now access the `$id`.

Unfortunately there is no `getElementsByClassName`, but I found one at http://pastebin.com/4qYMEGqV . Then your code would look like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html');
$class = getElementsByClassName($dom, 'this_is_our_div_of_interest');
```

`$class[0]` should now hold what you are looking for

Then maybe you should `strip_tags()`, if you just want the text.

Maybe look into DOMNode http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes ?

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, I know how to retrieve by class, I will update the question. The main question is how to traverse only leaf nodes, what xpath variable should I use!